# Unity3d: OnCollisionEnter only work if both collider's isTrigger=false

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

So the bullets have an OnCollisionEnter setup but will not trigger unless the character and the bullet are isTrigger=false
I wouldn't mind the character having isTrigger = false but the bullests need to be isTrigger=true. Otherwise the bullets impact moves the character which is undesirable. Both items have Rigidbodies.

Answer (score 1):

The `OnCollisionEnter` callback is used when none of the colliders has `isTrigger` enabled or set to true.

If any of the colliders you want to detect touching each other has `isTrigger` enabled then [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) should be used instead of `OnCollisionEnter`. In your case, use [`OnTriggerEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html) since one of your colliders has `isTrigger` enabled.

To learn more about this, read the collision matrix table from the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html).